# Keyboard key coming loose on a Dell Latitude 5880

Tags: laptop, keyboard, dell-latitude, laptop-repair, dell-keyboard

I have a Dell Latitude 5580 laptop. On the keyboard, one of the keys is loose. I need help to fit it in place. I have inspected the mechanism, nothing appears to be broken. The tiny metal mount looks intact. The tiny white scissor mechanism appears intact. The black key cap is definitely intact.

It looks to me that the white scissor part is not stuck properly onto the metal mount, because it is the front-facing side (closer to the space bar) that comes loose. When that happens, the front part of the key cap is lifted a little so the key cap is sloping away from me.

It is so tiny that it's hard for me to see if there's really anything broken or not. **I need someone with experience with these mechanisms to check, or explain what to look for.**

[Here's an Imgur album](https://imgur.com/a/IunHPG5) with more close-ups.

Here's the metal frame:
[image]

Here's the white scissor mechanism -- the circled holes are where the front hooks fit, and this is where it doesn't stay in place:
[image]

Comment: If the key doesn't clip back naturally into its place, then it's broken. Buy a new one, single keys are usually very cheap.

Comment: You might *carefully* pry up a little-used key-cap to see how it has been held in place. If that key-cap cannot be fixed, I'd put a *tiny* dab of silicone sealant on an edge to hold it in place until a new keyboard comes. A replacement keyboard is ~US$20, online. Be careful with silicone - some release a little bit of acetic acid in drying, which you don't want *inside* the machine.

Comment: first, fit the keytop to the assembly in the second picture ... that will show you how it is oriented on the base

Comment: @jsotola, the orientation isn't the issue :) That's clear enough. It just doesn't stay put.

Comment: which part does not stay put?

Comment: @jsotola I replaced the second photo for clarity.

Comment: the pink circled areas might clip to the keytop ... otherwise they slide under the hooks in the top picture ... the spacing looks similar

Comment: The circled areas *definitely* slide under the hooks in the top picture. The key cap clips onto the area you can see at the back/top of the image, and also slides along the pegs on the front corners of the scissor. @jsotola